# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml.dom.NodeFilter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins-pipeline

I am facing below error on the Jenkins environment,

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\tmp\\test_temp1\\test\\data\\test.py", line 5, in <module>
  from xml.dom import minidom
File "C:\\tool\\python\\3.9.5.0.2\\python-3.9.5.amd64\\lib\\xml\\dom\\minidom.py", line 23, in <module>
   from xml.dom.xmlbuilder import DOMImplementationLS, DocumentLS
File "C:\\tool\\python\\3.9.5.0.2\\python-3.9.5.amd64\\lib\\xml\\dom\\xmlbuilder.py", line 6, in <module>
  from xml.dom.NodeFilter import NodeFilter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml.dom.NodeFilter'
```

`test.py` file

```
line 1: import os
line 2: import sys
line 3: import json
line 4: import re
line 5: from xml.dom import minidom
... 
... 
docs = minidom.parse(file)
```

Ayn idea how to fix this error?

Comment: I'm not sure but Python's modules for XML may use `C/C++` library like `libxml` which you may have to install manually.

Comment: Do you happen to have any directories or modules in your project named `xml` or `xml.py`? The `xml.dom.NodeFilter` module is [part of the standard library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.5/Lib/xml/dom/NodeFilter.py) and should always be present, unless you are using a non-standard Python build or something odd like that. My best guess would be that you have a package or module in your project that is shadowing the `xml` namespace or something like that. My next guess would be that you're not using an official build of Python on your Jenkins server.